# Browsers are not able to show changes made in .css file

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, css, cache, browsers

I have made some changes in `Myfile.css` file in my sharepoint project. after making changes to `Myfile.css` file. I right click the file and do "copy to sharepoint root". I see the message in out put window: `"Copy to sharepoint root succeeded!"`

But when i open the browser and see the page, i could not see changes on page. Then I press F12 and inspect the respective element where i make changes, it shows the old version of my `Myfile.css` file. I could not see the changes that i made in `myfile.css`? why is that?

I guess browsers shows cached page. It did not takes changes from sharepoint. What i need to do ?

What I need to change in IE, Chroom and Firefox?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When in your site, the feature Minimal Download strategy is activated, the changes in CSS is not effective.

You need press ctrl + f5 or disable this feature.

Comment: @downVote, you can't ask each user to press ctrl + f5. Shashank Reddy's solution is optimal and logical.

Comment: I agree with you, I wanted to emphasize the issue of "Minimal Download strategy"

Comment: it may be that only using the ctrl + f5 does not cause the desired effect, you know?

Answer (score 2):

Try adding a query string at the end of the style sheet reference. Like,

`<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="myFile.css?v=1">`.

That way the browser downloads it again and does not use the cached copy. Change the query string value every time you run into this issue.

Answer (score 1):

There are two reasons that it can happen:

> 1. Browser is picking up Caches CSS file
> 2. If you upload file in SharePoint (not in _layouts folder), and it is not published as major version, user won't be getting CSS with
>      latest changes.
>
> But in both cases, you need to provide some query string like version
>   number for CSS file:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/Style Library/Assets/css/base.css?v=2.1"/>
```